# How to extract day of week and day from a Date object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I want to set all the dates and days within this month. Like I want to extract it as
`Sat 13`, `Sun 14`, `Mon 15`... and so on. What is the best possible solution?

Code reference is as:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    
    return dat;
};

const getDates = (startDate, stopDate) => {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = startDate;

    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    }
    return dateArray;
};

const dateArray2 = getDates(new Date(), new Date().addDays(30));

useEffect(() => {
    setNewDate(dateArray2);
    setCurrentMonth(monthNames[d.getMonth()]);
}, []);

return (
    <>
        {
            newDate.map((data) => (
                <h2>{newDate.toString()}</h2>
            ))
        }
    </>
)
```

Getting output as:

```
Sat Mar 13 2021 14:41:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Sun Mar 14 2021 14:41:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Mon Mar 15 2021 14:41:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Following is the codesandbox link for reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jotw6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods like `getDay()` and `getDate()` which can be useful in this scenario. Here's how we can achieve what you are trying to do.

- `currDay()` converts the days in digits into days in String format.
- By using `getDay()` and `getDate()`, we can get just the day of the week and the date.

```
const currday = (dayInDig) => {
    if(dayInDig === 1){
      return "Mon";
    }
    else if(dayInDig === 2){
      return "Tue";
    }
    else if(dayInDig === 3){
      return "Wed";
    }
    else if(dayInDig === 4){
      return "Thurs";
    }
    else if(dayInDig === 5){
      return "Fri";
    }
    else if(dayInDig === 6){
      return "Sat";
    }
    else{
      return "Sun";
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>{currentMonth}</h3>
      {newDate.map((data) => (
        <h2>{currday(data.getDay())} {data.getDate()}</h2>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gux1g?file=/demo.js:1258-1980). Please let me know if i have missed something.

Comment: Awesome... very neat, clean and concise answer... easy to understand... Thanks

Comment: Well one small query... How to color only 1st element i.e day which is 13th

Comment: @Pranav please ask a different question for that. There are several ways to achieve that. Btw if the answer was useful, you can appreciate by upvoting it.

Comment: OK... no problem

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the `Date.toString()` method is as you wish, I'd simply use `split()` to extract the entries in the Date you want.

```js
const getFormattedDate = (date) => {
    const splitString = date.toString().split();
    return `${splitString[0]} ${splitString[2]}`
}
```

Alternatively, if you wish to alter the day (e.g to get the full name), you could create an array and then the indexes of the array will match the day number:

```js
const daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const getDayOfWeek = (date) => daysOfWeek[date.getDay()]
```